# How do I go about validating Data in Html?

Tags: javascript, html, json, database, validation

Wanted to know how I could possibly get and verify data from Html maybe by a datasource like a db or json? Basically what im trying to do is make an input field where someone would enter in a specific code and if its valid, it would download something.

I would usually know how to do this but im drawing a blank and i cant think of it. nor can I find the solution anywhere.

Comment: Could you please give us more informations, example ? Maybe regexp !

Answer (score 0):

For sure it is easier to think if there is some example, but what if you add an event listener on your input (e.g. focusout), and send the inputs value to the server. You can validate it on the server and send back a success or error message to start or refuse the downloading process.

Comment: there is no server setup currently, I was hoping to have it all work locally for now... until I put it online. Do I absolutely need a server right now?

Comment: I also wanted to mention that this login system should work a little bit like Microsoft's Windows Download page. (where you would enter in a purchased key and be able to download)

Comment: @danielsulux Yes i get the goal of it, but if you want to validate any of user input, you'll need something to "compare" with... How you build your app on your machine? There must be some local server environment to work with :) There you should write your server logic too.